# Create an gradle configuration with a filetree (not an archive)

Tags: java, gradle, war, ear, exploded

I have an ear format project with multiple war modules.

Using the standard EAR mechanisms for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  deploy project(path: "war1", configuration: "archives")
  deploy project(path: "war2", configuration: "archives")
}
```

I can create an exploded EAR output that kinda looks like this:

```
exploded-ear
 |-- war1.war
 \-- war2.war
```

However what I really want is

```
exploded-ear
 |-- exploded-war1
 \-- exploded-war2
```

I've been looking for a while and the `configuration` mechanisms in Gradle don't seem to allow for anything that is *not* an archive.  What I want is to define a configuration that references a fileTree (which would be the location of the exploded war in my subprojects) so that my ear (and consequently my exploded ear) contain exploded wars.